# chromeOptions.add_experimental_option no such attribute

Tags: python, plugins, selenium-chromedriver

I wish to do a direct download of a PDF and not display in Chrome's pdf view plugin
The Python code I found is

```
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"plugins.plugins_disabled" : ["Chrome PDF Viewer"]}
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
driver=webdriver.Chrome('/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver', chrome_options=chromeOptions)
```

chromeOptions does not have an  add_experimental_option function/methodP.
Is there a way to make this work please.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the proper way to initialize chrome options:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
```

I believe that is your issue. I tested this code and it worked for me:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
prefs = {"plugins.plugins_disabled" : ["Chrome PDF Viewer"]}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

For more information you can read the docs [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.chrome.options) regarding the Chrome WebDriver API for Selenium

Comment: Thanks but no banana.   Executing code in python 2.7.6 from selenium import webdriver,from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options,chrome_options = Options()      then     dir(chrome_options) 
There is no add_experimental_option as an attribute.

Comment: My webdriver version is 2.25.0

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason the method add_experimental_option does not appear. Possibly this is because I am using a Linux install. My goal is to download a series of PDFs automatically. A work around is to first get the PDF in the pdf-viewer by finding a web element with the click() command. this loads the PDF into the viewer, then read the contents of the URL bar, the use the PDF address to make a call to the Linux operating system running the dowload command "wget" to obtain the PDF file. That is:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('browzine-direct-to-pdf-link').click()
pdfAddress=driver.current_url
os.system("wget %s -P /home/keir/Downloads/pdfs" % pdfAddress)
```